# Are there any differences between "any" and "*"?

Tags: jsdoc

Looking at https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc, it seems like `{any}` and `{*}` are interchangeable.

However, https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Types-in-the-Closure-Type-System makes no mention of `{any}`, and differentiates between "any" and "all".

Is there a difference between `any` and `*`?

Answer (score 2):

Checking the sources of the Typescript compiler (The one that parses the JSDoc for typings) it shows that `any`, `*` (JSDoc ALL Type) and `?` (JSDoc Unknown/ANY Type) are treated the same:

**[TypeScript/src/compiler/checker.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b58721fe15a9d58aa9c2b53b6e6fdb7966f56d2c/src/compiler/checker.ts#L16821-L16826)**

```js
function getTypeFromTypeNodeWorker(node: TypeNode): Type {
    switch (node.kind) {
        case SyntaxKind.AnyKeyword:
        case SyntaxKind.JSDocAllType:
        case SyntaxKind.JSDocUnknownType:
            return anyType;
        // ...
```

Also, the logic for the Javascript to Typescript file transformer does the same:

**[TypeScript/src/services/codefixes/annotateWithTypeFromJSDoc.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b58721fe15a9d58aa9c2b53b6e6fdb7966f56d2c/src/services/codefixes/annotateWithTypeFromJSDoc.ts#L76-L80)**

```js
function transformJSDocType(node: TypeNode): TypeNode {
    switch (node.kind) {
        case SyntaxKind.JSDocAllType:
        case SyntaxKind.JSDocUnknownType:
            return factory.createTypeReferenceNode("any", emptyArray);
        // ...
```